# Adding a vertical line by using a flag in the data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df<-
 FORM  TIME   CONC  
  0     1      5
  0     2      10 
  0     5      11
  1     6      14
  1     7      15
```

I am plotting `TIME` versus `CONC`. I would like to add a vertical line at the `TIME` when the formulation changes from `FORM 1` to `FORM 2`. I want to make my code for plotting so it can detect when the formulation changes automatically.

How should I write it in the ggplot line below:

```
plotobj <- plotobj + vline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = ??), linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
```

Comment: in the case above, the vertical line should be added at `TIME=6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read you correctly, this should help out:

library(ggplot2)

```
df = data.frame(FORM=c(0,0,0,1,1),TIME=c(1,2,5,6,7),CONC=c(5,10,11,14,15))

ggplot()+
   geom_line(data=df,aes(x=TIME,y=CONC))+
   geom_vline(xintercept = min(df$TIME[grep(1,df$FORM)]), linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
```

What is actually important:

`min(df$TIME[grep(1,df$FORM)])`

`grep` gives indexes for all `FORM` values equal to 1. We extract these and chose the one from the row with the smallest value of `TIME` using `min`. Finally using this index we pick the correponding value from `df$TIME`.

Comment: `min(df$TIME[grep(1,df$FORM)])` Adding `min` outside helps if the columns are not sorted in order.